# calling a function itself in a controller sails js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I know this same question has been asked before but the previous questions were in different languages and on different frameworks, and I tried all the methods mentioned in previous questions' answers but found no luck.

so here it is again.

I have a controller in my sails js app named `orderController` 
code is:

```
module.exports = {
    order_history: async function(req, res){
        //get a response from an API and it is saved in nData
        if(nData.status_code == 0 && nData.result == 'succeed'){
            res.ok(nData.data);
        }else{
            updateCredentials();
            order_history(req, res);
        }
    },

};
```

now if there are expired credentials then it updates the credentials and I want it to repeat itself so it can return the proper response in case of expired credentials. I do not want another request to be sent for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to create a helper with the logic for order_history that you call from within the controller. If it fails, you can do the update_credentials, then call it again. I say this because sails is built with the idea that a controller's purpose is to be a specific response to a specific request endpoint and not meant to be reusable code. That's where the helper comes in, it's purpose is to be a globally available function. The benefit of doing it this way is that you won't end up in a situation where the order-history fails for a reason other than needing to update credentials, calls itself, fails for that reason again, updates credentials, calls itself... You can have it try updating credentials, then if it fails again respond with an error message.